# How do I refactor this MySQL query (2 tables)?

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables:

[TABLE: xg_posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT5UF.png)

[TABLE: xg_postmeta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhvZp.png)

Then, I do this:

```
SELECT xg_posts.post_title,
xg_posts.post_content,
CASE WHEN xg_postmeta.meta_key="bgmp_address" THEN xg_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END AS address,
CASE WHEN xg_postmeta.meta_key="bgmp_latitude" THEN xg_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END AS latitude,
CASE WHEN xg_postmeta.meta_key="bgmp_longitude" THEN xg_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END AS longitude
FROM xg_postmeta, xg_posts
WHERE xg_posts.post_type = "bgmp"
AND xg_postmeta.post_id = xg_posts.ID
AND (xg_postmeta.meta_key = "bgmp_address"
OR xg_postmeta.meta_key = "bgmp_latitude"
OR xg_postmeta.meta_key = "bgmp_longitude")
ORDER BY xg_posts.post_title ASC
```

And get this:
[Result from mentioned query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2okAN.png)

But, what I need is 1 ROW with all data.
For ex.

> post_title | post_content | address | longitude | latitude
>
> A.C.A. San Lorenzo (Est. 21145) | AVDA. SAN MARTIN 2898,SAN LORENZO |
> -32.7161131 | -60.7314613

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group & aggregate. Note the `max( )` and the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT  xg_posts.post_title,
        xg_posts.post_content,
        max(CASE WHEN xg_postmeta.meta_key="bgmp_address" THEN xg_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS address,
        max(CASE WHEN xg_postmeta.meta_key="bgmp_latitude" THEN xg_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS latitude,
        max(CASE WHEN xg_postmeta.meta_key="bgmp_longitude" THEN xg_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END AS longitude
FROM    xg_postmeta, xg_posts
WHERE   xg_posts.post_type = "bgmp"
    AND xg_postmeta.post_id = xg_posts.ID
    AND (xg_postmeta.meta_key = "bgmp_address"
    OR  xg_postmeta.meta_key = "bgmp_latitude"
    OR  xg_postmeta.meta_key = "bgmp_longitude")
GROUP BY xg_posts.post_title,
         xg_posts.post_content
ORDER BY xg_posts.post_title ASC
```

Depending on what `post_content` is about, you might need to apply `max` on it too and remove it from the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT  xg_posts.post_title,
        max(xg_posts.post_content) AS post_content,
        max(CASE WHEN xg_postmeta.meta_key="bgmp_address" THEN xg_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS address,
        max(CASE WHEN xg_postmeta.meta_key="bgmp_latitude" THEN xg_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS latitude,
        max(CASE WHEN xg_postmeta.meta_key="bgmp_longitude" THEN xg_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END AS longitude
FROM    xg_postmeta, xg_posts
WHERE   xg_posts.post_type = "bgmp"
    AND xg_postmeta.post_id = xg_posts.ID
    AND (xg_postmeta.meta_key = "bgmp_address"
    OR  xg_postmeta.meta_key = "bgmp_latitude"
    OR  xg_postmeta.meta_key = "bgmp_longitude")
GROUP BY xg_posts.post_title
ORDER BY xg_posts.post_title ASC
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what i need.
I tried with both cases and they were ok.